# pyinstaller [7220] failed to execute script main modulenotfound error

Tags: python, pyinstaller

This is written with python and running on windows.
I want to export my project to an .exe file, but I have some problems with pyinstaller.

I tried to use pyinstaller on 1 file, and again as a dir but got the same results.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module name 'numpy.random.common'

The error I got in below screenshot.

[image]

I`m using numpy in 2 files: docs.py and collection.py

The project has some dirs with jpegs inside them and 3 .py files.
My project dir looks like that:

- /collection:
  -- /pages ( contain jpgs )
  -- /company ( contain jpgs )
  -- index.jpg
- /docs:
  -- /company ( contain jpgs )
  -- /doc_type ( contain jpgs )
  -- /pages ( contain jpgs )
- /venv
- /web:
  -- /css
  -- /js
  -- index.html
- collection.py
- docs.py
- main.py
- configs.json

I expect to have a single exe file that will launch my program.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried adding `hidden-import=numpy.random.common` flag?

Comment: Thank you @M.R. Adding the flag --hidden-import=numpy.random.common did solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try upgrading your pyinstaller or if still the problem persists try adding the numpy in hidden imports in spec file.
or import the numpy.random.common at the top

Comment: Thank you. Solved by adding the flag --hidden-import=numpy.random.common.